# sublime text : replace with increment number

Tags: sublimetext3

For example i have this string :

```
line1
bob
line2
line3
Fred
line4
Jack
```

I want to replace the **'line#' with 'line# is row#'** . so become :

```
line1 is row1
bob
line2 is row2
line3 is row3
Fred
line4 is row4
Jack
```

How to set this up ? The number is in sequential and there's no skip number or anything fancy. The lowest number is the first match and highest number is the last match.

Comment: Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)".
Did you research this? Where? If it didn't help tell us why. What did you try? If you didn't try, why not? If you did, what did you do? We'd like to see your minimal attempt to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try **Find and Replace** with **regular expression** to do this work.

For your case,

1. List item
2. In Sublime text, go to Find Menu -> Find
   Or you can just use Ctrl+F / Cmd+F.
3. Input `(line(\d+))` in Find and `\1 is row\2` in Replace, and Replace All. Then, you will get what you want.

`\d+` selects the number after string "line", and `()` get the group. That is, **line#** is the first group, and **#** is the second group. 
The replacement string `\1` indicates **line#**, and `\2` indicates **#**.

[image]